# Replace the value on a column based on the match, obtained using regex, on another column (Python Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
       AGENCY| CLIENT
     ___________________________
     AAA     | CLIENT_ONE
     AAB     | CLIENT_TWO SOMETHING
     AAF     | CLIENT_TWO SOMETHING and 55
     KAK     | CLIENT THREE
```

If the column CLIENT contains the string 'CLIENT_TWO' (followed by something or not), I want to replace the value of the corresponding column AGENCY with the string 'HELLO'. The final result should look like this:

```
       AGENCY| CLIENT
     ___________________________
     AAA     | CLIENT_ONE
     HELLO   | CLIENT_TWO SOMETHING
     HELLO   | CLIENT_TWO SOMETHING else 55
     KAK     | CLIENT THREE
```

How can I do it using regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.contains` and `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['CLIENT'].str.contains('CLIENT_TWO'), 'AGENCY'] = 'HELLO'
```

Comment: Thank you. I could not figure out the '.str.contains' part alone!